# unwanted flick effect on mousemove event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a frame(parent) and one rectangle inside it(child) and I want to move this rectangle on x-axis based on mouse position ... whenever I try to move this rectangle I see flick effect ... can someone guide me how to fix this?

```js
 let frame = document.querySelector('.frame') ;
        let slider = document.querySelector('.frame .slider') ; 
        let mouseX = undefined ;
        frame.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            mouseX = e.offsetX ;
            slider.style.left = mouseX + 'px' ;
        }) ;
```

```css
 html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        body{
            padding: 0 ;
            margin: 0 ;
        }
        .frame{
            width: 75vw ;
            height: 75vh;
            border: 4px solid rgb(220,220,220) ;
            position: relative ;
            top: 50% ;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%) ;
        }
        .frame .slider {
            position: absolute ;
            width: 1% ;
            height: 100%;
            left: 100% ;
            background-color: rgb(30,30,30) ;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mouseX = e.clientX ;` instead of `mouseX = e.offsetX ;` because offsetX will reset when your mouse move over slider and flick will be there for a second hope this will help :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        body{
            padding: 0 ;
            margin: 0 ;
        }
        .frame{
            width: 75vw ;
            height: 75vh;
            border: 4px solid rgb(220,220,220) ;
            position: relative ;
            top: 50% ;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%) ;
        }
        .frame .slider {
            position: absolute ;
            width: 1% ;
            height: 100%;
            left: 100% ;
            background-color: rgb(30,30,30) ;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let frame = document.querySelector('.frame') ;
        let slider = document.querySelector('.frame .slider') ; 
        let mouseX = undefined ;
        frame.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){ 
            mouseX = e.clientX ;
            slider.style.left = mouseX - frame.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
            
        }) ;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```